# Using COUNTIFS with checking string and comparing values

Tags: excel

I have the following excel sheet:

```
  Value
2 50
3 60
4 50
5 0
6 0
7 60
```

I am trying to count the number of times when comparing 2 rows a time the first or second is bigger by `Value` and `Value` is not `0`.

For example:

I am currently using:

```
=IFS(A2>A3;"Original";A2<A3;"Fake";A2=A3;"Equal")
```

Which simply adds a text value to column `B` by checking 2 `Values`. What I'd like to add is a statement - `& Value>0`.

Expected output:

```
  Value   State
2 50      Fake
3 60
4 50      (empty because row 5 is 0)
5 0
6 0       (empty because row 6 is 0)
7 60
```

In short - how can I count the number of occurrences when condition #1 is met and condition #2 is met, when the second condition is not a text value but a number comparison?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you add what the expected output is for your table?

Comment: Hi @urdearboy, I've added the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following formula:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE((A2>A3)*(A3<>0)*1+(A2<A3)*(A2<>0)*2+(A2=A3)*(A2<>0)*3;"Original";"Fake";"Equal");"")
```

[image]

**Edit**

With condition that the formula works every second row.

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(((A2>A3)*(A3<>0)*1 + (A2<A3)*(A2<>0)*2+(A2=A3)*(A2<>0)*3)*(MOD(ROW();2)=0);"Original";"Fake";"Equal");"")
```

Comment: Hi @basic, row 2 is good, row 3 is not, because it is comparing row 3 and row 4, whereas I only need to compare 2 by 2 rows, so only row 2,4,6,8... should have the formula.

Comment: Well, then you can copy formula every other row or add a condition that the formula return result in every second row. See edit.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a command to paste copied cells into every second row.